# contents of the web page(readability view)

Tags: java, html

I'm new to java programming. I want only the web contents of the page. but the program I got gives me the `html` tags with the content which i don't want.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you.

My code looks like this:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: you want only the contents or only the tags?

Comment: i want only the contents

Comment: Could you not use something like JSoup to parse the page to get the content?

Comment: jsoup actually gives you the text file.i wanted only the contents which we get in readability mode in firebox.is there any library for this ??

Answer (score 1):

If you really want only a small portion of the web page, you'll have to parse the HTML page you receive. There is no other way around. When you use your InputStreamReader to read the content of your page, you'll get the same thing your browser gets.

The only difference between the browser and your code is that the browser interprets the content.

You'll need to parse the HTML (XML) content you got to find the correct text.

Here is a nice tutorial you can follow to use the built-in Java XML parser: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parser.htm

Comment: can i somehow modify this program and get the required output

Comment: Yes, but you would have to add a "lot" of code to get the content of one HTML tag.